Flutter How to make plug-in dependencies dependent on users to install at runtime
Flutter How to make plug-in dependencies dependent on users to install at runtime、
Similar to js
"peerDependencies": {
  "sortablejs": "*",
  "@standard-semi/vars": "*",
  "@types/sortablejs": "*",
  "vue": "*"
}

I have a flutter project example that introduces its own encapsulated plug-in theme_design. The code is based on flex_color_scheme. How can I allow users to explicitly introduce flex_color_scheme when referencing theme_design plug-in, so that flex_color_scheme in theme_design depends on the flex_color_scheme explicitly referenced by the user?
